# Kubernetes subnet and docker subnet

Tags: kubernetes

When you promote/bootstrap a kubernetes cluster, and lets say you use the default subnet for flannel - 10.244.0.0/16.  Does this subnet have to match the docker bridge subnet? (At least that's how I'm configured in my environment)

Thanks!

Comment: Not only does it not have to, it is a highly problematic thing to make that SDN CIDR overlap with **any** in-use CIDR in your network. It is certainly possible to use one of the CNI IPAM tools to let someone outside of the cluster own those address spaces, but I've never seen it done in practice

Comment: I'm mainly talking about Docker SDN and Kubernetes POD SDN - best practice these two are different?

Comment: Yes, for sure, otherwise docker may attempt to route traffic into its own network, which isn't aware of the SDN, and traffic will `/dev/null`